# Client rendering JSON vs GPB (Protocol Buffers)

Tags: java, json, perl, protocol-buffers

I have read a lot about the pros and cons of Protocol Buffers (GPB) and JSON.
I have a service that will be providing the output, in one of these two formats.
So if the client using the service is mainly rendering the data to the front end (mainly a browser), then which of the two is best to use?

Other factors to be considered are:

- Maintainability
- Need of constant change
- Learning curve
- Scalability

Comment: Honestly, I have never heard of GPB.  Could your provide a link?  But if I had a choice, I would say that my first instinct is to go with JSON if the intended device is a browser.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Protocol_Buffers

Comment: You should call that "Protocol Buffers" or "ProtoBuf" in you question.  "GBP" is not a common abbreviation for Protocol Buffers".

Answer (score 2):

The "mainly browser" is enough to conclude: json.

Protobuf is very handy, and is designed to be highly performant (cheaper to process, smaller output) and very version tolerant **but** browsers are better at processing JSON.

Answer (score 1):

- Maintainability

  Of what? Your protocol? Your application? That has nothing to do with your choice of serialiser.

  Of the serialiser itself? There isn't any maintainence needed for JSON. JSON and its libraries are stable. Don't know about GPB.
- Need of constant change

  Has nothing to do with your choice of serialisation, but with your choice of protocol.
- Learning curve

  JSON: `my $json = encode_json($data);`, and similar on the other side. done.

  GPB: Don't know. Looks like a slightly more since you need to define your data format.
- Scalability

  Has nothing to do with your choice of serialisation, but with your choice of protocol and data structures.

Comment: GPB is google protocol buffer just for clarification.

Comment: I know. I linked to it earlier.

Comment: Actually, I disagree on your "scalability" and "maintenace" / "change" points re protobuf: protobuf is specifically designed for scalability, with dense output (smaller than json etc), and cheap processing (especially compared to text protocols). And in terms of comparable serializers, it is designed for simple version tolerance. it is more commonly used on server-to-server APIs though.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Version tolerance is a feature of the protocol. Has nothing to do with JSON. Same goes for scalability and maintenance of the protocol. Whether the protocol is scalable and maintainable or not has nothing to do with whether it uses JSON at some point or not.

Comment: @ikehami sorry but I disagree. A key point of scalability is doing more with less. Getting more information using less CPU and less bandwidth. For high throughput systems, that really really matters. Protobuf offers that. Json requires more processing (CPU) and more bandwidth.

Comment: @ikehami with regards versioning: note I said "comparable serializers", meaning performance focused binary serializers. Some of those are significantly less version tolerant. So again: this ***is*** a feature of the serializer.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Not at all. What makes it "text" serialisers so forward-compatible is the fact that the format is saved in the file as long with the data (in the form of field names). If you stored that in a "binary" file too, you'd have exactly the same forward-compatibility. (Could be done by storing the record definitions once in the file.) So again, it's comes down to higher-level decisions.

Comment: @ikegami whether field defs are included is a serializer implementation detail. Many such do not, for brevity. Some serializers don't even use field headers.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Ok, what did you change the subject to now? First it was JSON vs GPB, then text vs binary, now you're talking about the limitations of some other unnamed and unrelated formats? That some other format doesn't let you store arbitrary data is not relevant to this conversation, my answer, or the OP's question.

Comment: @ikegami I haven't changed the subject once: you stated that scalability and version-tolerance is not related to the serializer. I simply disagree, with reasons (and considerable experience). The text vs binary etc is part of that explanation.

Comment: @Marc Gravell, Fine, let me qualify: including both "text" and "binary" serialisers, excluding specialised serialisers.